# How to access the value of view controller into the tableview inside tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in Swift and I am not able to access IBOutlet variable in tableview cell inside tableview cell.

My code is something like this.

In view controller:

```
@IBOutlet var lblPopupTitle: UILabel!
```

In Tableview Inside Cell:

```
 cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.item
 cell.btnEdit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnEdit), for: .touchUpInside)
```

In Tableview Cell:

```
class AttendanceInOutCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var txtStartAt: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func btnEditClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell: AttendanceInsideCell = tableAway.cellForRow(at: index) as! AttendanceInsideCell

        lblPopupTitle.text = cell.txtAwayStart.text

    }
}
```

lblPopupTitle show me "Use of unresolved identifier 'lblPopupTitle'". How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

Protocol- Delegate approach:

```
    protocol PassDataDelagate: class {
     func passtextFieldText(_ startText: String)
    }
```

Make a protocol in class:

```
    AttendanceInOutCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var txtStartAt: UITextField!

    weak var textDelegate: PassDataDelagate?

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            
        }
        
        
        @objc func btnEditClick(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
            let cell: AttendanceInsideCell = tableAway.cellForRow(at: index) as! AttendanceInsideCell
    textDelegate?.passtextFieldText(cell.txtAwayStart.text)
        }
    }
```

Inside Tableview Cell, add this line:

```
     cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.item
     cell.textDelegate = self
     cell.btnEdit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnEdit), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Add this in view controller:

```
func passtextFieldText(_ startText: String) {
       lblPopupTitle.text = startText
}
```

P.S: You can also pass multiple information in the delegate function if you want.

Comment: func passtextFieldText is not getting call and if  I write cell.textDelegate = self it shows me error Value of type 'insideTableviewCell' has no member 'textDelegate'

Comment: Add like this
extension Your_ViewController_Name: PassDataDelagate {  
  func passtextFieldText(_ startText: String) {
       lblPopupTitle.text = startText
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol AttendanceDelegate: class {
   func didTapOnBtn(_ popUpTitle: String)
}

class AttendanceInOutCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var txtStartAt: UITextField!
    weak var delegate: AttendanceDelegate?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func btnEditClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell: AttendanceInsideCell = tableAway.cellForRow(at: index) as! AttendanceInsideCell //( I'm not getting this from where you get this tableAway variable) // So I m just telling you how you can set lblpopupTitle.text in viewController

        lblPopupTitle.text = cell.txtAwayStart.text // remove this line
        self.delegate.didTapOnBtn(cell.txtAwayStart.text) // please unwrap the textfield text before passing it as parameter

    }
}



// for view controller 
// there must be as tableview cellforRowAt function where you are creating your cell
// so after creating the cell instance
// add this line ( cell.delegate = self) and return cell
// now add extension to your controller

extension ViewController: AttendanceDelegate {
   func didTapOnBtn(_ popUpTitle: String) {
       lblPopupTitle.text = popUpTitle
     
   }
}
```